# Netty tcp connections handled plummets after few weeks

Tags: java, netty, nio, server

I have about 20k gps devices (frequency of 10 secs) reporting to two servers in active-active configuration (i.e around 10k connections per server). Everything works fine for about 2 weeks then suddenly number of connections per server plummets to around 2k. There are not many (~100) connections in state other than ESTABLISHED.

I do not recieve any exceptions from the application or netty. Sometimes i do get a series of ReadTimeoutException(s) which i have handled in code by closing the channel.

After getting the application restarted once or sometimes twice the things become fine. I have tried to find the Root Cause but cannot find a suitable action plan in absence of exceptions and inability to replicate the issue on my dev machine.

Has someone faced such an issue?

Can you suggest an action plan to investigate the issue. I have talked to IT Infrastructe teams to check on firewall level and network level but they are uncooperative as they perceive it as an act of blaming things on them. Can i run some commands on the linux server  next time such issue occurs to get more insight. What would be a proper set of things i could ask the infrastructure team to examine for more insight.

Comment: Do you have some logs?

Comment: probably could track cpu/mem usage for a week or so to see if spike causing host to stop accepting connections?